# Trouble with JSON-parsing

Tags: json, knockout.js

The following is the result from an HttpMapRoute "serviceUrl.

```
<ArrayOfProject>
   <Project>
      <AssignedUserId>5</AssignedUserId>   
      <CreatedByUserId>1</CreatedByUserId>
      <CreatedOnDate>2013-08-15T01:18:37.443</CreatedOnDate>
      <LastModifiedByUserId>1</LastModifiedByUserId>
      <LastModifiedOnDate>2013-08-15T01:24:57.953</LastModifiedOnDate>
      <ProjectDescription>Testing javascript and MVVM with DNN-platform
      </ProjectDescription>
      <ProjectId>1</ProjectId>
      <ProjectName>javascript and DNN</ProjectName>
      <Purpose>For fun</Purpose>
   </Project>
   <Project>
      <AssignedUserId>5</AssignedUserId>   
      <CreatedByUserId>1</CreatedByUserId>
      <CreatedOnDate>2013-08-15T01:18:37.443</CreatedOnDate>
      <LastModifiedByUserId>1</LastModifiedByUserId>
      <LastModifiedOnDate>2013-08-15T01:27:57.419</LastModifiedOnDate>
      <ProjectDescription>DNN Module design in development and Skins
      </ProjectDescription>
      <ProjectId>2</ProjectId>
      <ProjectName>CSS systems in DNN</ProjectName>
   </Project>
</ArrayOfProject>
```

My JSON-call is the following:

```
self.projectCollection = ko.observableArray([]); 

$.getJSON(serviceUrl, function (allData) {
        var i = 0;
        $.each(allData, self.projectCollection.push(new Project(allData[i++])));
    });
```

...
where Project is a function:

```
function Project(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.projectname = ko.observable(data.ProjectName);
    self.description = ko.observable(data.ProjectDescription);
    self.assigneduserid = ko.observable(data.AssignedUserId);
    self.createdondate = ko.observable(data.CreatedOnDate);
    self.createdbyuserid = ko.observable(data.CreatedByUserId);
    self.lastmodifiedondate = ko.observable(data.LastModifiedOnDate);
    self.lastmodifiedbyuserid = ko.observable(data.LastModifiedByUserId);
}
```

Why isn´t my "projectColletion" populated with more than the first Project ?

Comment: The response is XML, not JSON. You cannot use `$.getJSON` to load XML data.

Comment: that looks like xml, does that get turned into an actual json string somewhere along the line before your `$.getJSON` gets it?

Answer (score 0):

if it is actual xml that will be gotten then do the following:

```
$.get(serviceUrl, {
   dataType: 'xml',
   success: function (allData){
       $.each(allData.find("Project"), function(index,value){
          self.projectCollection.push(new Project(value))
       }); 
   }
}
```

Comment: The response is how it is presented in my browser when addressing the `http://localhost/$serviceUrl`...

Might be the presentation in the browser maybe?
If it was xml then I assume the getJSON would get the first record either?

Comment: If that is what you are getting in your browser then its xml and not json, which means you need to use the $.get function that i have in the answer to get the data

Comment: That makes sense. :)

Thing is I actually got it to work with this code:

  $.getJSON(serviceUrl, function (allData) {
        var i = 0;
        $.each(allData, function (i, fb) {
            self.projectCollection.push(new Project2(allData[i++]));
        });
    });